# Simple question on combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a simple question. Is it ok to say that a combination is a subset containing one of all possible permutations?

Comment: A $k$-combination of an $n$-element set $S$ is a $k$-element subset of $S$.  The number of such subsets is $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$.

Comment: Thank you,  @N.F.Taussig. I misunderstood everything when I read that each combination of k elements can be associated with the k! permutations that consist of those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is wrong because the word "permutation" implies that order matters, while "combination" implies that order does not matter. While they are both sets, they are not exactly related as the elements of permutations set are subtly different from the elements of the combinations set: one is a list of objects and the other is a list of ordered objects.

Comment: Thank you, @bkarthik.

Comment: Comments are for asking clarifying questions or pointing out mistakes. Commenting "thank you" is seen as spam and many people will not take kindly to it. Nonetheless you're welcome! :)